# passing props in React with a map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, components, state

I know how to pass basic props in React but I am a bit stumped on this one. Rather than try to explain all of it in this paragraph I think showing will do better justice to the problem.

Here is how it was **before** trying to break it off into its own separate component.

```
    { <div className="flex-item-main">
         <ol>
            {this.state.thoughts.map((thought, index)=> 
                <DisplayPoem className='displayPoem' key={index} onClick={() => { this.handleDeleteClick(index) }} name='Delete Thoughts' value={thought} />
            )}
          </ol>
         </div> }
```

Here is how it will look as its own separate component taking props from the parent:

```
    { <div className="flex-item-main">
         <ol>
            {this.props.thoughtsProp.map((thought, index)=> 
                <DisplayPoem className='displayPoem' key={index} onClick={this.props.onClick} name={this.props.name} value={thought} />
            )}
          </ol>
         </div> }
```

Here is the parent component passing down the props:   I have no idea what to do with  `onClick={() => { this.handleDeleteClick(index) }}` as I need `index` from the `.map()` function in the component. I hope any of this made sense and I am happy to add updates, im not sure how to explain the problem which is probably why im having trouble solving it. Still new to React.

```
         <DisplayPoemList thoughtsProp={this.state.thoughts}  onClick={() => { this.handleDeleteClick(index) }} name='Delete Thoughts' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the arrow function from props and pass you method as a prop.
Change this code (look at the `onClick`):

```
<DisplayPoemList thoughtsProp={this.state.thoughts}  onClick={() => { this.handleDeleteClick(index) }} name='Delete Thoughts' />
```

To this code:

```
<DisplayPoemList thoughtsProp={this.state.thoughts}  onClick={this.handleDeleteClick } name='Delete Thoughts' />
```

Then your `DisplayPoemList` will get a function `onClick` that expecting for `index` when it called.
Use an arrow function to create an instance of the function with an index in a scope for each element.

```
    { <div className="flex-item-main">
         <ol>
            {this.props.thoughtsProp.map((thought, index)=> 
                <DisplayPoem className='displayPoem' key={index} onClick={() => this.props.onClick(index)} name={this.props.name} value={thought} />
            )}
          </ol>
         </div> }
```